# Installing pdftotext on Windows (for use with R, 'tm' package)

Tags: r, tm, pdftotext, xpdf

I am having trouble using R, 'tm' package, to read in .pdf files.
Specifically, I try to run the following code:

```
library(tm)
filename = "myfile.pdf"

tmp1 <- readPDF(PdftotextOptions="-layout")
doc <- tmp1(elem=list(uri=filename),language="en",id="id1")
doc[1:15]
```

...which gives me the error:

```
Error in readPDF(PdftotextOptions = "-layout") : 
  unused argument (PdftotextOptions = "-layout")
```

I assume this is due to the fact that the pdftotext program (part of xpdf, http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) has not been installed correctly on my machine, so that R cannot access it.

**What are the steps to install xpdf/pdftotext correctly such that the above R code can be executed?** (I am aware of similar questions already posted, however they don't address the same issue)

Comment: what happens if you call `readPDF`without the option `-layout`?

Comment: try using the package pdftools. That avoids the hassle of installing xpdf.

Comment: @Karsten: running the code without the -layout setting gives me the following error: >>> Error in system2("pdftotext", c(control$text, shQuote(x), "-"), stdout = TRUE) :   '"pdftotext"' not found <<<

Comment: @user3641140 I will look into pdftools - but is installing xpdf really such a great hassle?

Comment: Did you add the xpdf path to the Environmental Variables?

Comment: @Wyldsoul I will look into that, thanks

Comment: Installing xpdf is no hassle at all, and it is required for this function of `tm`. Unzip the [file](ftp://ftp.foolabs.com/pub/xpdf/xpdfbin-win-3.04.zip) and read the instructions.

Comment: @RHertel, Wyldsoul I still get the same error... I've unpacked the zip file to "C:\Program Files\xpdf" and added the path to the PATH variable, exactly as in this instruction: [link](https://mbnuijten.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/manualinstallationxpdflakens.pdf)

Comment: Just a side note: Can you use the Rpoppler package? It allows you to do the roughly the same without installing external software. Just install package Rpoppler and in `readPDF()` use the argument `engine` to set the poppler as the extraction engine.

Answer (score 1):

`PdftotextOptions` is no parameter of `readPDF`. `readPDF` has a `control` parameter, which expects a list. So correct use would be:

```
if(all(file.exists(Sys.which(c("pdfinfo", "pdftotext"))))) { 
  tmp1 <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))
  doc <- tmp1(elem=list(uri=filename),language="en",id="id1")
}
```

Comment: This seems to work at first glance. I will accept your answer soon after looking into it further.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
setwd('C:/xpdf/bin64')
```

It works for me.